Redgate SQL Source Control: TFS Checkin Notes
We currently use Redgate for our SQL Source Control in SQL Management Studio, which has never been set up.  I have VSTS connected and can Get Latest and view Commits.  However, our source control check-in policy requirement is being violated as we have Source Control Check-in Notes; two required fields 'Ticket No' and 'Ticket Title'.
I can check in changes using the #ignorepolicies flag to ignore the source control policy.  However, is there a way of setting these required note fields at check-in through SQL Source Control in SQL Management Studio?

Have you reached out to Redgate to ask? They have, historically, been good at answering such questions when I've contacted them.

No, not yet.  We are out of support so thought to check here before I go down that route...

@M666ONA - does this help? https://documentation.red-gate.com/soc/configuring/disable-tfs-policy-checking

@DavidAtkinson Thanks David, sorry for the late response.  That fix does remove the need to use the #ignorepolicies flag when checking in which makes things easier.

Redgate is moving from SQL Source Control to their new product Flyway Desktop, so this check-in problem could be a moot point:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/moving-from-sql-source-control-to-flyway-desktop-152109390.html
